# How to connect decoupled webapp components?

Tags: api, optimization, server

I decided to decouple my webapp into:

1. API component that is hosted on a server, connects to the database, contains some logic and returns results to consumer app.
2. Consumer app, hosted on a server, has HTML templates, view logic and client JavaScript code. It sends requests to the component 1, puts results into templates and renders views.

As the consumer app needs API component to function, it must have low latency connection. As a result, should I put both API and consumer components on one server, and optimize the connection between them somehow? Or is it fine to have them on different servers, just have them fast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern web-applications tend to generate HTML on the client (the browser) using libraries like Angular. This way the server does not serve HTML, rather it serves the web application (static files) to the client and provides an API for the client to invoke. The client fetches the data from the server API and renders the HTML.

> As the consumer app needs API component to function, it must have low latency connection.

Because the API serves pure data (JSON, CSV, etc.) and no rendered HTML, it results in less data being transferred on the wire between the client and the server. It also compresses better.

Comment: response is right, though some applications use a mixed approach with some content being templated at the server side. In any case, if you still need to use a template engine on the server for your HTML, you can host both servers on the same data center and create a private network between them. Then ensure that when using the API from the other server you do it through the private network and not the internet. Many hosting/¿all? providers don't charge for private traffic and the latency will be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Any overhead adds latency. At the end of the day it depends on what's your quality bar for fast.

You can definitely mitigate physical latency by using an internal network between your client app and your API, but if you are rendering on the client, the browser still has to go back to the API on every service call.

To really take advantage of your internal network, you would need an isomorphic app (previously called universal) in which your app can be rendered on both the client and the server side. In a client rendering app, on the first call and every time the browser is refreshed, extra work has to be done (download client-side code, make service calls and rendering). However, an isomorphic rendering will make the call to the api through the private network, render the view and provide it to the client app on the first call and when the browser is refreshed.

The other problem with client rendering is SEO. Web crawlers don't handle javascript rendering (Google is the only claiming improvements in the matter). They just expect html as a response to their requests and a page with no data is useless for indexing purposes. However, universal rendering again solve this issue.

There's a really good blog entry in airbnb that talks about it: http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/

Also a couple of links regarding private networks in cloud environments:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-digitalocean-private-networking
https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/